# How do I load a H1 tag first

Tags: javascript, time, html, performance-testing

I just took a look at my page speeds which you can see at,

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140310_A0_4Q3/1/details

There seems to be a delay loading my `<h1>` tag which is extending my page time. Is there a way to force the `<h1>` tag to load earlier?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Michael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your background image and the logo image(in the `h1` tag). Try to optimize them in a image editor, and save them for web. 
Also you should save them as `.jpeg`, as they are not transparent images, so you will save more from file size.
Later edit: If you want the transparent logo image, save it as jpeg for web, then use css `opacity`.

Comment: Thanks but I put the image into the h1 tag for SEO purposes. I was looking for a javasrcipt solution similar as this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474200/how-can-i-create-a-first-load-event-in-html-or-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

It's loading a PNG image (logo.png) file that is over 386 kb in size and takes time to download. Try reducing the size in your image editor if you're not content with the page load speed. Possibly making it a high quality jpeg if you don't absolutely need it to be png. Your page seemed to load fairly fast for me as it is.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I am looking for a javascript solution similar to this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19474200/how-can-i-create-a-first-load-event-in-html-or-javascript) Also since I posted this question I did change the image to a jpg but I do want to keep it as a png as I like the effect.